# Dragging formula with increasing count of variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Increase count in my formula while dragging across row

```
=SUMIF('Form Responses 1'!$C:$C,($B$1+3),'Form Responses 1'!$K:$K)
```

This is my formula. With `B1` a constant, how can i drag the formula across the entire row, so that it shows `B1+4`, `B1+5` etc.

Comment: Just use `COLUMN`. Replace `3` with `COLUMN(C1)` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `COLUMN`. Replace 3 with `COLUMN(C1)` for example. ;)

`COLUMN(C1)` gives you the column number of column `C`, thus the number `3` and dragging it over increases the number.